# webkit (safari/chrome) image positioning problems

Tags: html, image, layout, webkit

I have troubles with the image positioning on this page:

http://www.beatekoerner.com/new/works.html

Here's the basic HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="gridContainer">
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"><img src="./images/title.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</div>
<div id="maintext" class="tiles">
<div class="image"><a href="works/time.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/time.jpg"><h2>time</h2></a></div>
<div class="image"><a href="works/shame.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/shame.jpg"><h2>shame</h2></a></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#nav {  
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
}

#subnav {opacity: 0.7;}

#maintext { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 180px;
    height: 70%;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -100;  
}

#maintext img {
    padding: 10px;
    width: inherit;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.tiles {
    text-align: center;
}

#maintext.tiles img:hover {
    opacity:0.4; 
    outline: none;
}

.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   display: inline;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

The plan is to display the images in a regular grid, but somehow this does not *always* work with Safari and Chrome. One example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko5Wc.png]

So this seems to be a webkit-based problem. I have tried a bunch of things that seemed to help with similar issues, but so far nothing worked.

Also: Chrome does not allow to scroll on *some* smartphones. This behaviour seems random to me.

Does anyone have experience with browsers behaving like this?

edit: Fun fact: If the size of the browser is changed in Safari after the issue appears, the images line up just fine. This makes no sense.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Working perfectly fine in Safari 8, by the way.  Edit:  and without having to resize the window.

Comment: *"Does anyone have experience with browsers behaving like this?"* ~  Yes... it's usually invalid HTML =>  your `<meta name="description"...` tag is missing the closing `/>`.  That's not going to help things.

Comment: I've never heard of using the meta `keywords` tag repeatedly; once per each word.  Weird.  It's supposed to contain *"as strings separated by commas, relevant **words** associated with the content of the page"*.  See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: changed the meta tags, thanks for the heads up. safari 8 on my macbook pro does still show the same behaviour.

Comment: Now I'm seeing the issue in my Safari.  Your `keywords` tag is still messed up.  You are not supposed to put quotes around each word.  Simply put **one set** of quotes around the whole list of comma separated words.

Comment: hope i did it right this time. this is how it should look like btw: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gj5cfv8fu1fae7y/Bildschirmfoto%202015-03-20%20um%2017.28.54.png

Comment: any thoughts on the actual problems, @Sparky? i have set width and height for the involved images (following clues from other questions), but this didn't change anything.